# What is the difference between 收了 and 收到了?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles

What is the difference between 收了 and 收到了?
1. We say 我收了他的錢
2. But we don't say 我收了他的信, We say我收到他的信了

When do we use 收了 and 收到了?

Comment: 收到钱 has a different meaning from 收钱，see e.g.
bkrs：  **收钱**  receive/collect money/payments (from a customer/etc.)向顾客收钱
charge customers

秘密彩票的收钱人
bagman
 **收到** ：收到一笔钱  receive/obtain/get a sum of money, 收到应得的钱 receive due amount of money, 收到找回的零钱 accept the change

Answer (score 2):

> 我收到了他的信。/ 我收到他的信了。
>   I have received his letter.

Here, 收到了 usually indicates that something I received that was sent by other people actively. I just get it passively.

> 我收了他的钱。
>   I took his money. /  I accepted his money.

Here, 收了 just means I get his money. But you cannot tell whether the money is given by him actively or the money is given by my demand/request.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I can think from the actor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the word 到 indicates some form of completion:

> 我找到了我的鞋子
>   I found my shoes

or

> 我收到了他的信
>   I received his letter

In both cases, some action began (searching and sending, respectively) which then came to a completion (finding and receiving, respectively).

Thus, the statement 我收了他的钱 implies that you received money, but not through an active, time-consuming process. You just took the money.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I can see the difference from the process. Thanks a lot.